# Failing to understand and to fix a PWM spindle controller circuit

Tags: power, pwm, component-failure

My CNC controller worked for many hours without trouble. But recently the resistor R5 (red circle) started to melt each time I switch my CNC spindle on, and even at low RPMs. It is 100 ohms, compared to the large 2 ohms R3 and R4, so why does it drive so much current? And without blowing the optocoupler?

The schematics below was reverse engineered, so it may have some little errors, but I checked that it matches the circuit I am trying to fix.

Also, I do not need the STOP signal at the bottom (any clue what is it for btw? PWM feedback?). So removed R5 completely with the idea I would "remove" the loop in the bottom right of the schematics, but it then prevents the spindle from turning at all. How can it be?

Other hints:

- The spindle power supply line reads about 60VDC instead of stated 48V.
- the spindle resistance is about 2 ohms, the fuse never melts
- Initially, I realized that R4 was not soldered properly but I fixed it before changing R5 again. No luck, R5 burns again after a few seconds.
- I checked the PWM signal with a scope (OK), the MOSFET gate-source (Q1), the flyback diode (D4), the AL817 opto diode (U3), and they all seem OK.
- The C9 capacitor is larger than stated on the schematics (1000uF in place of 100). It is also OK, but the polarity leaves me puzzled.

[image]

Comment: Whats the wattage on that resistor? And you seem to be pumping way too much current through that LED.  20mA is the rated operating current for that LED.

Comment: I'm guessing that circuit is to detect the motor stalling (and starting). V across those two resistors will go to your 60V/4.

Comment: sorry I should have told: R5 is a 1/4W thru-hole resistor.
R3 and R4 are big ones though (they just do not heat).

Comment: I'm thinking it is more likely meant to be a 1K. Certainly no less than a 750. But those caps are also back asswards and HUGE....

Comment: Perhaps the C9 has gone and it leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have what looks like 48 V DC being produced by rectifying the AC36V input supply. This connects to your spindle motor(?) and it might take a big current at start up thus several tens of volts may be forced to the top of R5 (100 ohms). R5 feeds an opto diode that is grounded and so you might see 20 or 30 volts for several seconds across R5. This will dissipate a power of 4 watts to 9 watts for some short period of time while the spindle device is running up to speed.

If you are using a surface mount resistor, it will likely melt. It seems to me that 100 ohms is too low as it will also force up to 300 mA through the EL817 opto and this is rated for 60 mA absolute maximum.

These numbers I have used might be out by a factor of two or three but I definitely smell a problem with R5 being underpowered and too low in value. 1 kohm might be more appropriate.

> Also, I do not need the STOP signal at the bottom (any clue what is it
>   for btw? PWM feedback?)

No, because I have no idea what you have reverse engineered.

Comment: 60mA is the maximum.. 20mA is rated...

Comment: C9 and C10 are also upside down... which is probably where most of the 0.6A is going... Not even sure why they are there.... or so ridiculously large...

Comment: Something is just odd about that part of the circuit in general.

Comment: Yep, actually I am not the one who reverse-engineered it (source is http://maher-ramblings.blogspot.fr/2014/08/cnc-engraver-schematics-yoocnc-nt65-3x.html). It is a ~$1000 4 axis Chinese CNC (6040DQZ). The parts I have checked were OK though.

Comment: What is puzzling is why it worked for years, and then started to fail systematically. And mainly: why would the spindle not turn when i remove R5 !? I would better ditch all the mess with the STOP subcircuit, as I agree it really looks weird :(

Comment: @MoonCactus I'm thinking something mechanically has happened to the motor to increase the starting current time to the point where it is causing failure. Check your bearings and that the motor turns freely.

Comment: Yes, if the motor has started to get more frictional this could easily cause an excessive start up current and this translates to a higher voltage across R5 for a longer period of time.

Comment: @MoonCactus Or perhaps you recently added a bigger, heavier chuck?

Comment: Thanks guys, it makes sense. Actually the spindle motor is getting old. I also recently changed my controller (the one that generate the external PWM signals, and I remarked it went "too" low and could leave the spindle idle at some point, so may be it also goes higher than before at other end of the range). Still, the resistor was burning even for a very low PWM.

Comment: @MoonCactus it is important to monitor and use that STOP signal with whatever you are controlling this with. If the motor is stalled too long, the currents involved can degrade the motor significantly. And BTW 100R does not need much current to get really hot.. 50mA is too much. In this case that extra .15A going the wrong way through C9.. which is basically a short... was probably just enough extra current to allow the motor to start.

Comment: @MoonCactus also check your PWM frequency... It may be too low.

Comment: OK with 1K, R5 only smokes a little bit ;) The opto receives 1.2-2V on its input according to PWM. But the spindle no more turns. I tried to remove the large capacitor and it does not get better.

Comment: Maybe the MOSFET is damaged - maybe this began the process? What physical size is R5?

Comment: @Trevor I double checked it with a scope, it is OK. Also the controller comes with a manual PWM setup (by means of the NE555), idem.

Comment: @Andyaka I replaced the MOSFET to make sure, and I have put C9 back in the right polarization after checking it also (I also tried without). The resistor is a 1/4W (6mm long)

Comment: @MoonCactus check your voltages. What is across the motor when it wont start? What is across R3,R4? Also, what is the resistance from the motor to the top of Q1?

Answer (score 0):

If it worked OK for a while, then something is probably damaged. At the glance I see C9 that is reverse polarized. Entire monitoring circuit with opto and C9 should be a kind of overload protection circuit. When the huge C9 is being filled the LED starts to glow.

Now, the reversed cap can't live for long, so it is probably short and the R5 is overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was a lot of issues that triggered sequentially.
In the end here what I did, and it works again:

- changed R5 many times ;)
- fixed the reversed capacitor C9
- changed R2 & R3 (they were first shorted, loading R5 and the mosfet, and then left dead open), to a 10W ceramic one (2 ohms, had only this in stock). I think that being shorted killed the mosfet when I powered again the spindle thinking it was all good.
- changed the mosfet (and as it died it made the 555 overheat a lot)
- hence, changed the NE555 (it ended up always triggering the spindle)
- increased R2 to 100 ohms to protect the 555 next time
- added 100K between gate and ground on the mosfet to stabilize it (may be useless)

The STOP subcircuit indeed "monitors" the voltage drop on R2//R3 that will rise when the spindle is stalled (its current then increases).

- so I fixed R5 accordingly so the 817 triggers as it should after a few seconds

I am unable to tell what was the egg and what was the chicken though, but I suspect the spindle provoked it and not C9 (which did not die while being in the wrong polarity for years, weirdly). Idem, the EL817 did not die though it was fed way too much!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad you got it working. If c9 is electrolytic it likely would not die, just short out reversed. Electrolytics are used back to back all the time to make them bi-polar.

Comment: Do you think that making this the accepted answer actually is fair given all the advice received?

Comment: seriously no, I am not sure why/how I marked it so. Hard to choose between useful advices and hints (real information) and an actual solution (which this "summary" is not anyway). I revert it, sorry, but I would gladly have given the mark to both of you in the first place :/

Comment: It's always useful to receive feedback from the fixes made following recommendations and so that is good to see posted as an answer by the way!